# How can I pass a paramater that is not contained in the url when routing to a component using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, npm

I have this Vue.js SideBar component that I created that fetches JSON data.
This json data contains a list of names that map onto a url that again contains JSON data.

```
{ "applicants": "url1", "applications": "url2", "companies": "url3", "employees": "url4", "jobs": "url5", "recruiters": "url6", "reviews": "url6", ..... }
```

Now for every item in this JSON object I created a sidebar button that routs them towards a new page on the website.
This routing is not a problem, but now I want to pass that url to the component I'm routing towards.

This is my Sidebar component

```
<template>
    <aside>
        <h3>Menu</h3>
        <div v-for="(key, value) in menu_items" :key="key" class="menu">
            <button @click="push_to(value, key)" name="value" class="button">
                <span class="text">{{ value.toString().charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.toString().slice(1) }}</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </aside>
</template>

<script>
const URL = "https://groep35.webdev.ilabt.imec.be"
export default {

  data() {
    return {
        menu_items: []  
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    fetch(URL)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => this.menu_items = data)
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  },
  methods: {
    push_to(name, url){
        this.$router.push({ name: "menu-item", params: { link: name, url: url} })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This is my routing javascript file

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import MenuItem from '../views/MenuItem.vue'

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            component : Home,
            props: true
        },
        {
            path: '/:link',
            name: 'menu-item',
            component: MenuItem,
            props: true
        }

    ]
})

export default router
```

And this is my MenuItem component that I'm routing towards from the SideBar component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>{{this.$route.params.link}}</h1>
        <h1>{{this.$route.params.url}}</h1>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  
}
</script>
```

I've tried using props, vuex state storing, transfering paramaters and always had problems.
I think this really shouldn't be hard at all so I don't know where I'm going wrong.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't have a parameter called link. It does not render the page again even if the url changes. Does the url information contain an external url or just a local path? Also you don't need to use ‘this’ in the template.

Comment: If your goal is to use only the url value, you can use vue router props. https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no route declares no `:url` so this returns a blank page

### Vuex 3

pass data with vuex

```
import { router } from 'src/routes'

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    router: {
      namespaced: true,

      state: () => ({
        url: null
      }),

      mutations: {
        setUrl(state, url) {
          state.url = url
        }
      },

      actions: {
        pushToMenuItem({ commit }, name, url) {
          router.push({ name: "menu-item", params: { link: name })
          commit('setUrl', url)
        }
      },
    }
  }
})
```

Sidebar.vue

```js
...
  methods: {
    push_to(name, url){
        store.commit('router/pushToMenuItem', name, url)
    }
  }
...
```

### Pinia / Vue 3

stores/router.js

```
export const useRouterStore = defineStore('router', () => {
  const url = ref()
  const router = useRouter()

  function pushToMenuItem(name, url) {
    router.push({ name: "menu-item", params: { link: name })
    url.value = url
  }

  return { url, pushToMenuItem }
})
```

Sidebar.vue

```js
...
const { pushToMenuItem } = useRouterStore()
...
  methods: {
    push_to: pushToMenuItem 
  }
...
```

View.vue

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>{{route.params.link}}</h1>
        <h1>{{routerStore.url}}</h1>
    </div>
</template>


<script setup>
import { useRouterStore } from 'stores/router'
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'

const routerStore = useRouterStore()
const route = useRoute()
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you this really helped me! I'm using Vuex again now to solve my problem. But one thing. When I route to another page using the sidebar I now get the url I wanted, but when I refresh I lose the url again. Is there any way to keep this url on that page?

Comment: you can use the plugin `vuex-plugin-persistedstate` to store the entire state, but when the user copy it to browser other then, `url` also lost the only way to solve this is tv `url` format query `?url=` or hash

Comment: Thank you! Using queries solved my problems